Data not loading after reloading page in Blazor
I have a Razor page that needs to show my transactions and load it from database but.
When I visit the page for the first time, everything works fine, but when I refresh the page, all the data stops loading.
I'm a beginner and I don't know what it could be.
Here is my code
@page "/home"

@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using FinanceTracker.Components.Data
@using FinanceTracker.Services

@inject UserService UserService
@inject TransactionService TransactionService
@inject CustomAuthStateProvider AuthStateProvider
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<PageTitle>Dashboard</PageTitle>

<header class="header">
    <h1 class="page-title">Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="logout">
        <button @onclick="Logout" class="logout-btn">Logout</button>
    </div>
</header>

<main class="main">
    @if (transactions != null)
    {
        <div class="transaction-balance">
            <p class="transaction-balance-text">Cash</p>
            <p class="transaction-balance-amount">@GetTotalAmount()</p>
        </div>
    }

    <div class="transaction-list">
        @if (transactions != null)
        {
            <h2 class="transaction-heading">Last Transaction</h2>
            @foreach (var transaction in transactions)
            {
                <div class="transaction-item">
                    <div class="transaction-item-content">
                        @if (transaction.Type == "Receive")
                        {
                            <p class="transaction-item-amount green">+@transaction.Amount UAH</p>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <p class="transaction-item-amount">@transaction.Amount UAH</p>
                        }
                        <p class="transaction-item-description">@transaction.Description</p>
                    </div>
                    <img @onclick="() => DeleteTransaction(transaction.Id)" class="transaction-item-btn" src="Delete-button.svg.png"/>
                </div>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <p>Loading...</p>
        }
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ShowModal">Add Transaction</button>
</main>

<AddTransactionModal Visible="@showModal" />


@code{
    private List<Transaction> transactions; 
    public bool showModal = false;
   
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var login = authState.User.Identity.Name;

        if (login != null)
        {
            var user = await UserService.GetUserByLogin(login);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var userId = user.Id;
                await LoadTransactions(userId);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadTransactions(int userId)
    {
        transactions = await TransactionService.GetTransactionsByUserId(userId);
    }


I tried to debug my code, but I didn't see anything that could help me

Hi s0tka, what the Transaction in your code? System.Transactions.Transaction or somethings ? For this issue, it's better share a repo with us to debug it. If you could provide a sample, please don't forget to hide your sensitive information.

PROBLEM SOLVED
The problem was with my CustomAuthenticationState Service
The issue with the SetUser and GetAuthenticationStateAsync methods not retaining the user information across different pages likely stems from the CustomAuthStateProvider not persisting the user state. In a Blazor Server application, the authentication state is not retained across page reloads by default, and you need to implement a more persistent storage mechanism like session storage or cookies.
I added session storage and everything works now

Try to using below code,  the modified code can ensure that the data can be loaded normally.
@code{
    private List<Transaction> transactions;
    public bool showModal = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await LoadUserTransactions();
    }

    private async Task LoadUserTransactions()
    {
        try
        {
            var authState = await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var login = authState.User.Identity.Name;

            if (login != null)
            {
                var user = await UserService.GetUserByLogin(login);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var userId = user.Id;
                    await LoadTransactions(userId);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // add logic here to handle errors
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading transactions: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadTransactions(int userId)
    {
        transactions = await TransactionService.GetTransactionsByUserId(userId);
        StateHasChanged(); // make sure the data can be refresh in the page
    }

    private void ShowModal()
    {
        showModal = true;
        StateHasChanged(); 
    }

    private async Task DeleteTransaction(int transactionId)
    {
        await TransactionService.DeleteTransaction(transactionId);
        await LoadUserTransactions(); // reload data after deleting
    }

    private async Task Logout()
    {
        await AuthStateProvider.MarkUserAsLoggedOut();
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/");
    }

    private decimal GetTotalAmount()
    {
        return transactions?.Sum(t => t.Amount) ?? 0;
    }
}


It's still doesn't work
